# What to replace "this" in subclass methods with, when extracting them to an abstract superclass?

Tags: android, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

I have two Android activities A and B, which have a lot of methods in common. These methods use `this` in their method implementations. I am now abstracting these activities into an abstract superclass which extends `Activity`.

Should I leave the `this` as it is in the superclass's methods or do I need to change it to something else to ensure the right context is passed to the appropriate methods? If I need to change `this` to something else, please tell me what I should replace it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I leave the this as it is in the superclass's methods or do I
>   need to change it to something else to ensure the right context is
>   passed to the appropriate methods?

`this` refers to the current instance/object. Since abstract classes can't be instantiated, the only remaining possibility is the concrete implementation. So you don't need to replace `this`

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks